# Replace all non-quoted text with spaces

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file that looks like this

```py
"""Some docstring and stuff.

More lines, etc etc.

"""

a = 'Another quoted text and there\'s "more contents" ' + "anything with double-quotes and single quotes around it" + "more text. Doesn't matter what" \
    """\
    A multi-line statement here. Some arbitrary text

    """
```

And I want to read the file's contents and print out this replacement as efficiently possible:

```
"""Some docstring and stuff.

More lines, etc etc.

"""

    'Another quoted text and there\'s "more contents" '   "anything with double-quotes and single quotes around it"   "more text. Doesn't matter what"
    """
    A multi-line statement here. Some arbitrary text

    """
```

How can I do that? Ideally, I'd like the solution to use streams / unix pipes so that I don't have to pay the cost of writing the output to-disk. Is there a **linux command-line tool** that does this job effectively?

Comment: String as in "text that has quotes around it" or "Nested 'string-quotes' for example" or "More complicated exmaple \" because there's escaped \" characters"

I'll update the original post.

Comment: Then I must not know the exact word / definition you're thinking of, apologies. Feel free to edit the post yourself if you have some other, more precise definition then. Even the the terminology is off, I think I explained my case well enough.

Comment: I sort of understand what you want but can't think of any method for doing it that would be easier than just manually editing the document.  What sort of document is this anyway?  Why are there so many adjacent quotes?  What are the quoting rules for this document?  It looks like you have single quotes nested inside single quotes but in shell this is not allowed.

Comment: It's a Python file, in this case. Though I plan on running this on many files. So an automated solution is a must. And ideally, I'd like this solution to work with anything, not just Python files. The text isn't usually that bunched up like that but those are my "most complex scenarios", if that makes sense. 

To be clear, I just intend to pass the replaced text into another command-line program. But that tool can't handle the non-quoted parts. That's why I'm looking for something that can strip everything else away.